# Using attribute binding together with string interpolation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I want to build an accordion like the [example on the bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) but with dynamically loaded data using the angular 2 directive `*ngFor`. Therefore I tried to set the value of aria-controls dynamically too:

```
[attr.aria-controls]="{{item.itemId}}"
```

Apparently it is not possible to use attribute binding together with string interpolation in angular 2. The above code gives me the following error.

```
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected ...
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the following is enough:

```
[attr.aria-controls]="item.itemId"
```

This will evaluate the `item.itemId` expression and put the result in the `aria-controls` attribute.